# Add dates in format YY-MM-DD for each row of an ascii file using python

Tags: python, numpy, date

I have several ascii files including daily values for each month. For example I have the following file for month January

```
day val1    val2
1             0.00000000              0.00000000
2             0.00000000              0.00000000
3            47.00000000             59.68835831
4            31.00000000             31.09384918
5             0.00000000              0.00000000
6             9.00000000             13.57461262
7             0.00000000              0.00000000
8            13.00000000             40.37162399
9            31.00000000             74.39214325
10           37.00000000             44.71131897
11           42.00000000             30.92972755
12            0.00000000              0.00000000
13            0.00000000              0.00000000
14           28.00000000             36.55170822
15           26.00000000             38.96712875
16           18.00000000             48.36120605
17           37.00000000             71.38799286
18           29.00000000             39.89580917
19           19.00000000             27.67076302
20           14.00000000             23.26745033
21           21.00000000             21.28680229
22           17.00000000             19.07740593
23           19.00000000             11.41687393
24           11.00000000             15.21029568
25           20.00000000             38.57400894
26           31.00000000             30.63389587
27           23.00000000             27.23128700
28           13.00000000             28.33661079
29            7.00000000             33.86462784
30           12.00000000             23.77343559
31           31.00000000              6.44272470
```

I want to convert the day numbers (col "day") to dates in format such as YY-mm-dd

I tried the following

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

i=directory/"test.txt"

dates = np.loadtxt(i,skiprows=1,usecols = 0)
val1 = np.loadtxt(i,skiprows=1,usecols = 1)
val2 = np.loadtxt(i,skiprows=1,usecols = 2)

for day_num in range(1,32,1):        
    print(day_num)
    year = "2021"
    res = datetime.strptime(year + "-" + str(day_num), "%Y-%j").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

outfile=directory/"fin.csv"
np.savetxt(outfile,(str(res),val1,val2),delimiter=',')
```

but this is not working. How can I keep the strings of dates produced for each day and save them in the output file?

Edit: I get the following errors:

```
VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1424, in savetxt
    v = format % tuple(row) + newline
TypeError: must be real number, not str

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
np.savetxt(outfile,(str(res),data_obs,data_sim),delimiter=',')
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in savetxt
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1426, in savetxt
    raise TypeError("Mismatch between array dtype ('%s') and "
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%.18e')
```

Comment: Is the day column the day in January (ie 1 to 31), or the day of the year (1 to 365)?

Comment: @DS_London is the day of the month e.g. January

Comment: What errors do you get? eg what is in your directory variable?

Comment: @DS_London I edited my question and included the error.

Comment: the directory variable is just my path in my pc. I just not included it in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using DataFrames:

```
from pandas import read_csv
from datetime import datetime

#Read column-based text file with one or more spaces as separator
df = read_csv('test.txt',sep='\s+')

#Assume dates just in January (month=1)
#transform each element in 'day' column from number to string date
df['day'] = df['day'].transform(lambda d: datetime(2021,1,d).strftime('%y-%m-%d'))

#Output to csv file, dropping dataframe index
df.to_csv('fin.csv',index=None)
```